# stieß an der Ausfahrt mit Herrn H.s Auto zusammen. - What is the case for "Herrn"

Tags: grammatical-case

This is the first time I've encountered genitive case of a compound noun with a name (H.) and noun (Herrn), since *Herrn* is the same for three cases except nominative, it is not possible to tell whether it is genitive, accusative or dative. So which case is it then?

Comment: I don't consider *Herrn H.* as **compound noun**, which is the term for words like *Krankenhaus*; simplification helps to answer, e.g.  replacing *Herrn H.s* by *Antons*.

Comment: German is more inflected than English, but it's not completely inflected. So in general you can't tell case from the noun alone. An article helps, but sometimes you just have to use context or common sense. For example in *Die Katze frisst die Maus,* it's impossible to tell grammatically who is eating and who is being eaten, but only one interpretation is likely.

Comment: @guidot so what's the term for that? I am not a native English speaker so I haven't known how to call that phrase yet. Thanks!

Comment: I had to do some searching, but it seems to be a [Nominalphrase](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/progr@mm/5302), *nominal phrase* in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Genitive, because it's possession.Here a more obvious example:

- ... stieß mit des Einhorns Po zusammen.